# Backbone.js get event when clicking on same route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbonejs w/ routes and I'd like to know when a person has clicked on the same route that they are already on.

For example, if they are on `/#/home`, then they click a link again for the same route.  I tried to bind all, but it only seems to register if a route is actually changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but the following may help:

```
Backbone.history.on('all', function (name, e, route) {
    if(route === lastroute) {
        refresh();
    }
}
```

Be sure to use `Backbone.history.navigate('home', {trigger: true})` if you use this kind of navigation.

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't seem to trigger when I click on the same route.  So, I'm on `/#/` then I clicked on a link with `#/`